# C# SQL, Get rows affected by UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql

Essentially, what I am wondering if possible is how to retrieve the data from newly updated rows after executing a stored procedure.

For instance, say we have a simple SQL stored procedure

```
sp_PROCS_UPDATE_UpdateUserName:

    UPDATE users SET Name = "David";
```

From that, I want to be able to retrieve the actual records which names were updated, not just the count.

Is this even possible with C# ?

Comment: If you execute your command using "ExecuteNonQuery()" you will get back the number of row affected

Comment: Assuming SQL Server: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, try the below:

```
UPDATE users SET Name = "David" output inserted.*;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 

I have tried that and it works. However, the problem is that I have quite a huge list of stored procedures and was hoping that a C# solution was available.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in C#

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet using `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, you may also need to `using System.Data` as well.

This code sample will execute the query and return the affected rows.

```
var affectedRows = -1;
var cs = ""; // your connection string
try 
{
    var cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    cn.Open();
    using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = your_query; // TBD;
        var prm = new SqlParameter("prm", value); // as needed
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm); // as needed
        affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    /// and if you have nothing else to do.
    cn.Close();
    cn.Dispose();
    cn = null;

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Whoops! {0}", ex);
    // error handling
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that there is a large number of stored procedures so only some of them actually return data.

Updating the stored procedures is likely not a task that I or my team would prefer to do since it would take a lot of time to not only implement them, but to test them.

I was hoping this information was stored somewhere in the SqlCommand or something. It appears that it may not be.

Comment: you can get the affected rows in a stored procedure -- that's called `@@ROWCOUNT`, you can access it after the update statement.  more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017